# Tableau - How to switch columns dynamically by changing filter value?

Tags: tableau-desktop

Hello Tableau experts,

In the attached [tableau file link](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D58b00009zCr9LCAS/how-to-switch-columns-dynamically-by-changing-filter-value), I am trying to switch between the columns "TOTAL ELIGIBLES" and "SPECIAL ELIGIBLE" by changing the value from the filter "TYPE". The logic goes as:

IF TYPE =  "D" (only) then show SPECIAL ELIGIBLE
ELSE (in all other cases including multiple selection of TYPE, show TOTAL ELIGIBLES.

I have tried to accomplish the same by making a new Calculated field by the name of "ELGIBLE CALC" (pardon the spelling) but it does not seem to work with multiple selection of values from filter "TYPE".

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what you are trying to achieve can be accomplished using "Parameters", you may check this golden rulebook : https://public.tableau.com/views/12UseCasesforParameters/Overview?:showVizHome=no